# SQL - Combine 2 tables result and order them in a hierarchical way

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

**R_DEPT Table:**

```
DEPT_CD     DEPT_NM 
800          Dept A  
900          Dept B
620          Dept C
```

**R_UNIT Table**

```
UNIT_CD       UNIT_NAME       DEPT_CD 
8120            Unit_A          800
8121            Unit_A          800
8122            Unit_A          800
9120            Unit_B          900
9126            Unit_B          900
9127            Unit_B          900
6222            Unit_C          620
6223            Unit_C          620
6234            Unit_C          620
```

I want an output that combine the 2 tables based on the DEPT_CD key. The first 3 records comes from the R_DEPT table and are the parent records and the remaining record are from the R_Unit table and are the child records.  Each of the Department has Units under them.
I want to list all the Departments (from R_DEPT) first and then list all the Units (from R_UNIT) that belong to each Department and they should be ordered by the Department Code (DEPT_CD). Unit records should be listed only if their parent Department exist.
Element Type are hard-coded values depending on whether it is a department (DEP) or a Unit(COA).

**Here the SQL Query desired output:**

```
CLASS_ID            CD         NM           DEPT_CD         Element_Type
"Organization2"     800        Dept A       <blank>         "DEP"
"Organization2"     900        Dept B       <blank>         "DEP"
"Organization2"     620        Dept C       <blank>         "DEP"
"Organization2"     8120       Unit_A       800             "COA"
"Organization2"     8121       Unit_A       800             "COA"
"Organization2"     8122       Unit_A       800             "COA"
"Organization2"     9120       Unit_B       900             "COA"
"Organization2"     9126       Unit_B       900             "COA"
"Organization2"     9127       Unit_B       900             "COA"
"Organization2"     6222       Unit_C       620             "COA"
"Organization2"     6223       Unit_C       620             "COA"
"Organization2"     6234       Unit_C       620             "COA"
```

Here is the query I am working on:

```
Select
   "Organizaton2" as CLASS_ID
   DEPT_CD as CD,
   DEPT_NM as NM,
   UNIT_NM as DEPT_CD,
   '' as ELEMENT_TYPE
FROM
(select 
   'Organization2' as CLASS_ID,
   DEPT_CD as CD,
   DEPT_SH_NM as NM,
   '' as DEPT_CD,
   'DEP' as ELEMENT_TYPE
 FROM
   R_DEPT

 union All

 SELECT 
       'Organizaton2' as CLASS_ID
       , A.UNIT_CD as CD
       , A.UNIT_NM as NM
       , A.DEPT_CD as  DEPT_CD
       , 'COA' as ELEMENT_TYPE 
FROM 
       R_UNIT A, R_DEPT B ) TABLE_ALL

WHERE A.FY = 2014 AND
      A.act_fl = 1 AND
      B. act_fl = 1 AND
      B.DEPT_CD = A.DEPT_CD

ORDER BY A.DEPT_CD
```

Comment: You may use `JOIN` in your sql query. Please provide the query that you have tried.

Comment: your first question here I think. We don't just do things on demand for free, you must attempt the work first,  suggest you take the tour it will help you

Comment: @JoshKK I've helped formatted your question but if you really want anyone to help, you need to make sure your `desired output` section is correct. The format you specify in the comments does not seems to match the `desired output` section in your questions. Please make sure the question is correct and remove any confusing information (if your comment is incorrect, remove it. If the question is incorrect edit the question and remove your comment.)